# How to directly return to rootViewController? UIStoryboard (or update tableview)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, uistoryboardsegue, mknetworkkit

There are some questions I have found but the answers don't work with my code, therefore I ask a question of my own.

My objective is reloading a table view from a detailviewcontroller. I tap a cell, go to the detail and when I return to the table I want it updated. The thing is it doesn't update. So I decided it would be better to go back to the rootviewcontroller when certain thing happens on the detailviewcontroller but it still didn't work.

I am open to suggestions and advice feel free to comment!!

I download a video and when the video is downloaded I update the tableView.

Here is the code I am using:

I use MKNetworkKit btw.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *downloadPath = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];

    self.downloadOperation = [ApplicationDelegate.mainDownloader downloadVideoFrom:finalAddress
                                                                            toFile:downloadPath];

    [self.downloadOperation onDownloadProgressChanged:^(double progress) {

        //DLog(@"%.2f", progress*100.0);
        //self.downloadProgressBar.progress = progress;
    }];
    [self.downloadOperation onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation* completedRequest) {

//THIS DOES NOT WORK, dismissModalViewControllerAnimated.
        [[ApplicationDelegate.window rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        DLog(@"COMPLETED REQUEST: %@", completedRequest);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download completed"
                                                        message:@"The file is in your photo and video Library"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Thank you WebSurg!!", @"")
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];


// THIS IS WHAT I PREVIOUSLY TRIED.
//            NSDictionary *tableSecData = ApplicationDelegate.videoLibraryController.tableSectionData;
//            NSMutableArray *tempValuesDownloaded = [tableSecData objectForKey:@"Downloaded videos"];
//            NSMutableArray *tempValuesUndownloaded = [tableSecData objectForKey:@"Undownloaded videos"];
//            for (NSArray *videoArray in tempValuesUndownloaded) {
//                if ([[videoArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:self.videoDetailTitle.text]) {
//                    [tempValuesUndownloaded removeObject:videoArray];
//                    [tempValuesDownloaded addObject:videoArray];
//                }
//            }
//            [ApplicationDelegate.videoLibraryController.tableSectionData removeAllObjects];
//            ApplicationDelegate.videoLibraryController.tableSectionData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:tempValuesDownloaded, @"Downloaded videos", tempValuesUndownloaded, @"Undownloaded videos", nil];
//            [ApplicationDelegate.videoLibraryController.mainTableView reloadData];
    }
                                 onError:^(NSError* error) {

                                     DLog(@"%@", error);
                                     [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download failed" message:@"The download failed because of a connection error please try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss", @"") otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

                                 }];
} else {
    UIAlertView *failureAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Download status" message:@"Download failed, not enough free space." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil, nil];
    [failureAlert show];
}
```

Comment: Please log the values of the `ApplicationDelegate.window` and its `rootViewController` at the point where you say it doesn't work to verify they are valid objects.

Comment: I log them both and I get valid values: for instance, window sends: `<UIWindow: 0x87a1030; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x87a19d0>>`and rootviewcontroller: `<UINavigationController: 0x879f210>` If I return to the rootviewcontroller(navigationcontroller) it should send the viewcontroller that embedded that navigationcontroller right?